# An example of an ideal of order $12$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals, examples-counterexamples

> Provide an example of an ideal in $R=\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ that has order $12$, and indicate whether the ideal is a principal ideal (if it is, then identify the generator for the ideal).

Let 
$$I=\{(0,5),(1,0),(2,5),(3,0),(4,5),(5,0),(0,0),(1,5),(2,0),(3,5),(4,0),(5,5)\}.$$ 
Then $I$ is a principal ideal with $(1,5)$ as the generator. Does this work? If not, what else could possibly work or is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: What you wrote is $\mathbb{Z}_6\times\mathbb{Z}_2=\langle(1,0),(0,5)\rangle$.

Comment: Do you have an example of an ideal of order $12$ then? Not sure how else to go about it.

Comment: I think that you misunderstood my comment.  That is an ideal of $R$, you were asking for a more elegant solution.  By thinking about the divisors of $6$ and $10$, you can get the order of $12=6\cdot 2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that by the Chinese Remainder Theorem we have $$\Bbb{Z}_6 \times \Bbb{Z}_{10} \simeq \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_3 \times \Bbb{Z}_5$$
The only ideals in a product of fields are the "partial products"; so the example you provided, which as Michael Burr noted is
$$I = \Bbb{Z}_6 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \simeq \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_2 \times \Bbb{Z}_3$$
is the *only* ideal of order $12$ in $R$.

---

It isn't hard to see that $I = \langle (1,0), (0,5) \rangle$, because $1$ has order $6$ in $\Bbb{Z}_6$ and $5$ has order $2$ in $\Bbb{Z}_{10}$. As you observed, it then follows that $I$ is principal and generated by $(1,5)$, because
$$
(1,0) (1,5) = (1,0) \quad \text{and} \quad (0,1) (1,5) = (0,5)
$$

Comment: Ah so my answer is right then? $I$ is a principal ideal with $(1,5)$ as the generator.

Comment: Beh, I suck at this stuff. The generator is what Michael Burr listed right? $\langle(1,0),(0,5)\rangle$

Comment: Yes, it is, because $(1,0) (1,5) = (1,0)$ and $(0,1)(1,5) = (0,5)$, where those two elements generate $I$. *(In my previous comment I carelessly listed the additive group generated by $(1,5)$, which is why I deleted it)*

Comment: @riddler it is principal. It is also generated by $(1,0)$ and $(0,5)$. But your element also generates.

Comment: @quid Okay. So my 12-element ideal, if I am talking about "the" generator...then my ideal has $\{(1,0), (0,5)\}$ as a generating set.

Comment: @riddler there are many sets that generate this idea. When you are asked to if it is a principal ideal though you should say: it is generated by $(1,5)$ and this is a generator of this ideal. (But $(-1,5)$ would also be a generator, thus a generator not the generator.)

Comment: @riddler There is never only *one* generator of an ideal. You can find, though, *minimal* sets of generators (where you can't remove any elements and still generate the ideal), and you can wonder about the minimal size of these sets. An ideal is said to be *principal* if it can be generated by only one element, but there are always at least as many generators as there are units in the ring, because $\langle u a \rangle = \langle a \rangle$ if $u$ is a unit.

Comment: @A.P. By $\simeq$ you mean isomorphic to right? Isn't this usually denoted by $\cong$ or does the notation vary?

Comment: @riddler Yes, I mean isomorphic, and yes, there are different notations for it. Personally I prefer $\simeq$, but $\cong$ is common, too.

Answer (score 0):

The set you give is an ideal of order $12$, and as explained in another answer it is the only ideal.

It is in fact also principal, generated by $(1,5)$ as you said correctly, even though the additive group $(1,5)$ generates is only of order $6$.